# Magento 2 href to Add product link from template phtml

Tags: module, admin, adminhtml

I Have made custom admin page view module, now  i want add button there click on which should take user to add product URL .

i tried below but it is not working

```
<a href="<?PHP echo $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => 10, '_current' => true,'next'=>"1"]);
```

Comment: Try $block instead of $resultRedirect variable in phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?php 
        $prams = ['id' => 10, 'str2' => 'value2',];
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $prams]); ?>" />
```